# Jsf session timeout handling if user is not logged in

Tags: session, jsf

I want to do the below if the session expires:
- reset session before it ends if user is not logged so he continue normally. 
- redirect to login page if user is logged in.

I managed to do the second but I need to do the first.

I am working with jsf.

Comment: If the user is not logged in there is no session to expire: and taking a logged-in user to a login page is senseless. Do you mean 'online'?

Comment: The question its current form doesn't make sense. The duplicate answers your http://xyproblem.info.

Answer (score -1):

By Simple search, you can get the following answers

[Invoke method just before session expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943368/invoke-method-just-before-session-expires)

[How to call a method before the session object is destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756054/how-to-call-a-method-before-the-session-object-is-destroyed)

Comment: Next time, when you find duplicates, post a comment and vote for close instead of posting an "answer".